# Error when using Mule XPath an namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

Using Mule EE v2.5.2:

I have a Mule flow with a choice, that runs an XPath expression on the payload:

```
<choice doc:name="Is Fault?">
    <when expression="#[xpath('/iXML:Fault') != null]">
        <set-payload value="#[xpath('/iXML:Fault')]" doc:name="Retrieve Fault element"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
        <logger message="Exception Caught: #[payload.faultstring] - FaultCode #[payload.faultcode] - #[payload.detail.error]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Log Aorta Fault"/>
        <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true" doc:name="Throw exception for Aorta Fault">
            <not-filter>
                <payload-type-filter expectedType="com.vatit.blaze.esb.dragon.dto.Fault"/>
            </not-filter>
        </message-filter>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger message="Dragon message verified OK." level="TRACE" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

At this point the payload looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iXML:Envelope xmlns:iXML="urn:schemas-ixml-org:ixml.v1">
   <aseloginResponse>
      <iXML:Fault>
         <iXML:faultcode>0</iXML:faultcode>
         <iXML:faultstring>Unknown Aorta Fault Type</iXML:faultstring>
         <iXML:runcode>No</iXML:runcode>
         <iXML:detail>
            <error code="30001">Invalid Login</error>
         </iXML:detail>
      </iXML:Fault>
   </aseloginResponse>
</iXML:Envelope>
```

I have added a global (in the same XML file) namespace manager:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="iXML" uri="urn:schemas-ixml-org:ixml.v1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Yet, i still get a Mule error: *undeclared namespace prefix iXML* when it hits the XPath:

```
2015-01-27 11:45:08 ERROR CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:337 - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "iXML"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,27] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Undeclared namespace prefix "iXML"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,27] (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)
  org.mule.module.xml.stax.StaxSource$PseudoReader:208 (null)
2. com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "iXML"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,27] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
  org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl:502 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerException.html)
3. com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "iXML"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,27] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToDomDocument:83 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "iXML"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,27]
    at org.mule.module.xml.stax.StaxSource$PseudoReader.parse(StaxSource.java:208)
    at org.mule.module.xml.stax.StaxSource$PseudoReader.parse(StaxSource.java:188)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

2015-01-27 11:45:08 ERROR LoggerMessageProcessor:337 - Exception Caught: Execution of the expression "xpath('//Fault') != null" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream
```

What can i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works perfectly fine for me:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="iXML" uri="urn:schemas-ixml-org:ixml.v1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>

<flow name="test-http">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <choice doc:name="Is Fault?">
        <when expression="#[xpath('//iXML:Fault') != null]">
            <logger message="ERROR TERRIBLE" level="ERROR" doc:name="Log Aorta Fault" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Dragon message verified OK." level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Notice I slightly changed the XPath. I'm wondering wich version of Mule are you using? I just tried with 3.6.

Comment: My bad, the XML i was getting for subsequent rounds, did not include the ns definition. Your solution works fine, thanks Victor.